# aptana heavy load while writing code

Tags: eclipse, aptana, cpu-usage

Aptana is very slow and has an high cpu usage on my pc (Core2Quad, 8gb ram).

When starting it takes some minutes before i can "work" with it. It hangs a long time on Building workspace and indexing php. (up to 5 minutes and more)

I'm working with an ~70k LOC Project and SVN (.svn folders).

But the main problem is, that aptana hangs when I write my code.

for example:

```
 public function test (
```

- short moment  of thinking, and it hangs (maybe the code highlighter / failure check is buggy?)

I start Aptana already with " -vmargs -Xmx1024m -Xms512m" and it use ~300-400MB RAM. But CPU usage is in avarage ~15-20% of my quadcore ..

Have anybody an idea for an solution, ie. settings option or so, to resolve that performance issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new workspace. Maybe your Aptana configurations is corrupted.

To create a new workspace:

1. File->Switch Workspace->Others
2. Select a new path for example: C:\Users\myname\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace2
3. Restart

Comment: Its a little bit better, but not useable in productive environment. When I wrote an Function/Class or some thing else and don't close the code block, it hangs always and i have to write the function to the end 'blind'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's the version you are working on, but you can also update to the latest builds by following the instructions as preview.appcelerator.com.

Performance improvement are being done all the time. Also, check your error log (via the help menu). There might be something else going on that can hint about the problem.